# Installing Python Modules for a web2py application

Tags: python, module, web2py

How would I install the pythonmagick wand api for a web2py application for the conversion of image type of an upload field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pip install pgmagick
```

See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgmagick/0.5.7

This seems to be a Python wrapper around GraphcsMagick/ImageMagick.

From the PyPi page:

> pgmagick is a yet another boost.python based wrapper for GraphicsMagick

It's not ImageMagick, but you should get equivilent functionality from the looks of it.

Comment: And for using it i just need to import it normally , right ??

Comment: Follow it's documentation. Yes basically.